Apache kafka returning blank output
I can't run zookeper. I searched on internet but i didnt find any solutions. This question same but no solution in here
Kafka does not start blank output
I am trying to run zookeeper,kafka. ı am following this documentation https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart
zookeeper
kafka
